# can't receive UDP packages when wire-shark is off

Tags: c#, udp, wireshark

this is my first post in here. 
I have an embedded Ethernet PIC32 uC that is sending UDP packages on one specific port to my C# Program on my PC.
With C# i want to grab this packages as follows:

```
 UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient( 20011 );
 IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        while (true)
        {
           byte[] content = udpClient.Receive(ref sender);
        }
```

A package looks like this (wireshark):
Source: 192.168.1.38        Destination: 192.168.1.44    Protocol: UDP  Length:   122 Source port: 1000  Destination port: 20011

The interesting part is, that everything works fine as long as the wire-shark software is running in background! As soon as I stop listening on wire-shark no more packages in c# where received.

Does anyone has an idea what is happening here?

Thanks for your answers
Chris

Comment: Do you get any errors or exceptions?

Comment: no, it just waits on the receive line until I turn on wireshark again

Comment: honestly, that doesn't make any sense.  I know of no way that WireShark could have that effect.

Comment: Thats why I put the question to this portal :) makes no sense for me as well. But I tried it a couple of times, it is an absolute repetitiv problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the destination MAC Address was not resolved by the client correctly.
Thanks for your hints

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine really 192.168.1.44 ?
If not, you are seeing the packets because `wireshark` puts the infterface in "promiscous" mode while it's running; if it resets the interface to normal mode, you don't see them anymore.

Comment: Is there any other point to receive the packets when my interface is in promiscous mode?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entry in the Windows Firewall?  Does it work if you disable Windows Firewall temporarily?

Comment: same behavior when I turn off windows firewall completely